# Error installing Docker Desktop on Windows 11: "the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000135). Any suggestion to fix this?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop, windows-11

I am getting error installing Docker Desktop on Windows 11:
`the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000135)`
Any suggestion to fix this?

[Docker Desktop installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ1rR.png)

Answer (score 0):

ok, it was not a Docker issue!
It was Windows 11 update issue!

Besides Docker, even PowerShell stopped working.
And this all happened after latest Windows 11 update.

This did the "trick" of solving problem.
Just uninstalled Windows update as described here.

"How To Uninstall KB5013943 Update On Windows 11, Stop Installation Of KB5013943 Update on Windows 11"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WeEVpMqGdg

Hopefully this can help some other people,
and hopefully (?) somebody from Microsoft's Windows updates team can fix this soon.